# call controller action from .cshtml page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, razor

I am trying to call a controller action from a jquery UI dialog. 
What I have currently is this:

```
.html("<p><textarea name=\"TextMessage\" id=\"textItems\" rows=\"10\" cols=\"72\" /><br /><br /><input type=\"button\" style=\"float:right;\" id=\"submitData\" onclick=\"Test()\" value=\"Submit\" /></p>");
```

The script I am using to call the controller action is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Test() {
        $ajax({
            url: '<%= Url.Action("GetData", "Report") %>',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

And the controller action is this:

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetData()
        {
            return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I would like to know if I am doing something wrong, I am trying to get this to work but without any success. When I am trying directly to start the controller via http://localhost:1322/Report/GetData it works fine, so that means that the script is not setup properly.

Comment: If you are returning JSON, you need to set the dataType: 'json' property. You should also include and "error: function(..." in your ajax call.

Comment: It seems that you are missing the closing bracket on the `Test` function, but that may just be a typo.

Comment: @JackieChiles I updated the test function, see if it's ok, doesn't do anything as well

Comment: @rontornambe Is it possible to give me an example, that would help me a lot. Thx in advance

Comment: @Laziale: When you say that you are able to "start the controller directly," do you mean by navigating to that URL (in a browser), or do you mean that it works if you set that URL as the `url` parameter of the AJAX call? With your edit you now have a trailing semicolon after the closing bracket on `Test`, by the way.

Comment: @JackieChiles by navigating to that URL in a browser. Updated the script now, same result

Comment: @Laziale: It seems that it may indeed be an issue with your dialog, and not the script itself. If you set a breakpoint at the `Test` function in a JavaScript debugger is it hit? Do you get any JavaScript errors? Can you elaborate the dialog code?

Comment: Check your javascript console or install Firebug and debug the javscript. You will see what is going on

Comment: One error I see in your example is that you are missing the `.` in `$.ajax`. You should be getting the error `$ajax is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are calling an action method that is returning a `json` object you can use the [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Test() {
        $.getJSON(
            '@this.Url.Action("GetData", "Report")',
            function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: nothing is happening as well. The script I am trying to run is from jquery UI dialog, do you think that might be the reason why I am not getting anything? Thx

Comment: @Laziale if you add an `alert("")` on the first line of the `Test()` function, does it pop up when you click the button?

Comment: @Laziale you are using `getJSON()` now correct? Are you sure that you have included `jQquery` in your page? You can verify that by `alert($)` which should alert a function.

Comment: @Laziale additionally if you are using the `razor` view engine then you need to use the syntax `@this.Url.Action("GetData", "Report")` for generating the URL. Check the source to see what is actually be generated for the URL.

Comment: yes, I am getting this: function (a, b) {
    return new e.fn.init(a, b, h);
}

Comment: @Laziale view the source to see what is being generated for the URL. As I mentioned as well, if you are using the `razor` view engine, you will need to change your syntax.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7856/discussion-between-craig-and-laziale)

Answer (score 2):

You should try:

```
url:'@Url.Action("GetData", "Report")'
```

MVC will automatically add "Controller" to the end of the second parameter when it is looking for the controller.

### Edit:

This code may work:

```
function Test() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Report")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

### Edit 2:

Changed to use Razor syntax so that this code will work with Razor/MVC3.

Comment: You are missing the `.` in `$.ajax`

Comment: @JackieChiles with the code you provided now I am getting error 'bad request', so definitely something is happening in the background. Why bad request, any idea? Thx

Comment: @Craig: Thanks, perhaps that was the source of OP's problem- I just now saw that it was missing above (and your comment on it). Good catch!

Comment: @Laziale: That is strange. See my edited code though: try adding the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` line.

Comment: @Laziale: Also, you shouldn't need `[HttpGet]` on your controller action.

Comment: @JackieChiles Why are you saying the they shouldn't use `[HttpGet]` on the controller action? Though it is the default I am not aware of any reason that this would hurt anything.

Comment: @JackieChiles even with the updated function I am still getting bad request message when I am clicking the button.

Comment: @Craig: I wasn't saying OP shouldn't use it, I was only commenting that they shouldn't _need_ to use it. You're probably right that it's not hurting anything, but it's also unnecessary in this case.

Comment: My mistake...I could have sore it just said shouldn't. You're right, `HttpGet` is not necessary. Though adding `HttpGet` to an action will not harm anything, it is the default behavior of an action to respond to `GET` requests.

Answer (score 1):

You are using MVC-2 syntax on Url.Action. This should work:

```
function Test() {
  $.ajax(
    {
      url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Report")',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
      },
      error: function (x, err, desc) {
        alert(desc);
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try jsaction too:
http://jsaction.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

We can call Controller method using Javascript / Jquery very easily as follows:

Suppose following is the Controller method to be called returning an array of some class objects. Let the class is 'A'

```
public JsonResult SubMenu_Click(string param1, string param2)

    {
       A[] arr = null;
        try
        {
            Processing...
           Get Result and fill arr.

        }
        catch { }


        return Json(arr , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Following is the complex type (class)

```
public class A
 {

  public string property1 {get ; set ;}

  public string property2 {get ; set ;}

}
```

Now it was turn to call above controller method by JQUERY. Following is the Jquery function to call the controller method.

```
function callControllerMethod(value1 , value2) {
    var strMethodUrl = '@Url.Action("SubMenu_Click", "Home")?param1=value1  &param2=value2'
    $.getJSON(strMethodUrl, receieveResponse);
}


function receieveResponse(response) {

    if (response != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
           alert(response[i].property1);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above Jquery function ***'callControllerMethod'*** we develop controller method url  and put that in a variable named 'strMehodUrl' and call getJSON method of Jquery API.

***receieveResponse*** is the callback function receiving the response or return value of the controllers method.

Here we made use of JSON , since we can't make use of the C# class object

directly into the javascript function , so we converted the result (arr) in controller method into JSON object as follows:

***Json(arr , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);***

and returned that Json object.

Now in callback function of the Javascript / JQuery we can make use of this resultant JSON object and work accordingly to show response data on UI.

For more detail  [click here](http://counsellingbyabhi.blogspot.in/2013/02/calling-controllers-method-from.html)